Stopping time + constant for more general index-set
Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mathbb{P})$ be a Probabillity space, $I\subseteq [0,\infty)$ an Indexset which is closed under addition, i.e. for $a,b \in I $ holds $a+b\in I$ and let $\tau : \Omega \to I\cup \{\infty\}$ be a stopping time. Let $a\in I$.
For $I = [0,\infty)$ the proof is quite simple and a very nice and clear answer is given here.
For $I = \mathbb N$ or $I = \mathbb N_0$ the argument should be pretty much the same and those three cases are definitely the most important ones.
But I am wondering what happens in other cases, i.e. cases where we dont get that $t-a\in I$ just from knowing that $t\geq a$ (which we can always assume, since for $a > t$ the set $\{\tau + a \leq t\}$ is always empty and therefore $\cal F_t$ measurable).
Going into the proof, at some point we probably want to do something like $$\{\tau + a \leq t\} = \{\tau \leq t-a\} \in \cal F_{t-a} \subseteq \cal F_t$$ using that Filtrations are increasing but this argument fails, if $t-a \notin I$.
My question: How is the argument saved? Can this even happen (since $I$ is additively closed)?
Remark: I know this is quite similar to the linked post, but this is my first activity here and thus i dont own the right to comment, which i would have done instead of asking a new question.

I think we can prove our claim by extending  ${ \mathcal{F}{t} }{t \in I}$ to ${ \mathcal{G}{t} }{t \in[0,\infty)}$ such that $\mathcal{G}{t}=\mathcal{F}{t}$ for $t \in I$ and $\mathcal{G}{t{1}}=\mathcal{G}{t}\subseteq\mathcal{G}{t_{2}}$ for $t_{1},t_{2} \in I$, $t_1 <t<t_2$ and $(t_{1},t_{2})\not \in I$. We can construct ${ \mathcal{G}_{t} }$ if $I$ can be expressed as a countable union of intervals (here $I\ni{ x }=[x,x]$ is an interval) but I am not sure if this works for weird index sets $I$.

Suppose $t\in I$ but $t-a\notin I$. (In particular, $a>0$.)
Case 1. There exists a decreasing sequence $(s_n)\subset I$ with limit $t-a$. Notice that there exists $n_0$ such that $t-a<s_n<t$ for all $n\ge n_0$.
As such,
$$
\{\tau+a\le t\}=\cap_{n\ge n_0}\{\tau\le s_n\}.
$$
Each event $\{\tau\le s_n\}$ is in $\mathcal F_t$, hence so is their intersection.
Case 2. If there is no sequence as in Case 1, then for some $\epsilon>0$, $I\cap(t-a,t-a+\epsilon)=\emptyset$. Let $\epsilon^*>0$ be the supremum of such $\epsilon$s; in particular, $I\cap(t-a,t-a+\epsilon^*)=\emptyset$. If $t-a+\epsilon^*\in I$ then (noting that $t-a-\epsilon^*\le t$ because $t\in I$)
$$
\{\tau+a\le t\}=\{\tau\le t-a+\epsilon^*\}\in\mathcal F_{t-a+\epsilon^*}\subset\mathcal F_t,
$$
and we are done. If $t-a+\epsilon^*\notin I$, then there are elements of $I$ just to the right of $t-a+\epsilon^*$, and one can re-cycle the argument used in Case 1.
